# Charging Battery Series

Tags: battery-charging

I have two 9,900 mAh 18650 Li ion batteries in series, originally 3.7 V now around 7.4 V . I'm completely lost on how to make a USB C charging port for the series. Originally was going to use USB C charging ports taken from old Elfbars. Any guidance?

Comment: Hayden - Welcome. (a) As you're new here, please read the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, as they differ from typical forums. (b) It's not an answer to your charging question, but you said: "*9,900 mah 18650 li ion batteries*" - FYI that capacity is impossible, with existing technology, in an 18650 cell size and any claiming that capacity are fakes. See test results [here](https://lygte-info.dk/info/BatteriesRidiculousRatings%20UK.html) and [here](https://danyk.cz/test18650_en.html). Beware.

Answer (score 0):

USB-C port outputs only 5VDC except in case the port is specially constructed to give more AND the connected device knows how to ask more. There's specified a digital communication protocol for that purpose. Some chargers have that capability implemented.

To charge a 7.4 volts battery from USB-C you could in theory have your own circuit which persuades the port to output high enough voltage, say 9V and you only limit the current somehow - even a resistor would do the trick, but it wastes about 25% of the energy.

But it isn't that simple. As said, the USB port needs a command to output more than 5V. A programmed computer is needed to perform that discussion. In addition to stay in the safe side the charging should be properly controlled. It must be stopped automatically when it's ready. And using multiple cells in series needs that the cells are equal.

So, you are not asking anything trivial. My suggestion: Get a charger board which is intended to charge 2 cells in series. I cannot recommend one, I have only seen advertisements of such boards. Get a voltage boosting model which accepts 5V input.   Note: I wouldn't leave such item alone before thorough testing. I charge my cells with commercial chargers. The reason is that controlling the charging properly and safely is a little tricky. Read this for a start: https://www.saft.com/energizing-iot/charging-your-lithium-ion-batteries-5-expert-tips-longer-lifespan